# How to stop banding from re-appearing on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using banding to highlight some areas, with a section in between with a fixed colour. It should look like this.

[image]

Sometimes, when I enter a number in the blue area in the middle, the banding appears:

[image]

I have no idea why this happens. I keep re-applying a fixed colour to those cells, using a macro, but sometimes the banding just keeps coming back.

Any ideas?

Here is an editable document that shows the problem, putting a value in F3 re-introduces the banding in that section, but putting a value in F9 does not. I'm a bit baffled why the problem only affects column F as well, not E or G.

The cells that are pale blue should stay pale blue, and not pick up the orange and white colour banding when values are entered.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17zRq27A6_ow56WNfbidGL07hTrbXc4i4Oco-auTictQ/edit?usp=sharing

Here's another document that is not editable, in case someone messes up the first, request access and I will grant it, or save a copy in your Google Drive account.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sFbm91dUQ0xJ4CpCnWD-DLw5qLR2RXdUCmON1_ayHmk/edit?usp=sharing

If you click on cell B2 and open up the "Alternating colours" dialog, it shows the area as overlapping column E. This is clearly wrong, and is a symptom of the problem. I should not be surprised that the banding reappears when I enter a value in cell E3.

However, if you click on cell B9 and open up "Alternating colours", it shows that the banding area does NOT overlap column E. Nonetheless, enter a value in cell E9 and the banding expands. This is the bug: why are the alternating colours expanding to cover column E when I enter a value in it?

Comment: I don't think you need script to do this simple task. In fact, the script may be the problem. Share a link to a new sheet (no script active) and manually enter some data into the target range. In a side note, explain what parts of the range should be colored, how they should be colored and if there are any "rules" to this. Then share the link to that sheet, being sure to set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." Either I or someone else here should be able to easily set up the color scheme for you there.

Comment: Also, while you say "when I enter a number in the blue area," entering manually has a different outcome from copying and pasting. When you copy and paste straight from one cell or range to another, you also copy and paste the formatting from the source cell or range. If this is what you're actually doing (copying, not entering data), try using Ctrl-Alt-V (Paste Special) instead of just Ctrl-V to paste; then click the clipboard icon that appears lower right of the paste range and select "Paste values only."

Comment: Definitely just typing in a value, not copy paste. And a whole chunk gets the banding applied, not just the cell I copy into. I will share the sheet though... I will see if I can cut it down to a minimal test case.

Comment: @PhilHibbs Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Done, thanks @marikamitsos

Comment: I think I fixed it. Funny how you look at a problem differently once you've talked about it with other people!

Comment: @PhilHibbs Solutions should be posted as an answer, not as a question edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I can fix this by editing the Alternating Colours properties, I don't think this functionality was as sophisticated when I added it, and I had not gone back and looked at it again. The banding in some areas was overlapping with the blue, but not in others.

Hmmm, nope. Banding keeps extending to the right, covering the blue area. I have disabled the code that re-applies formatting.

Ok I've finally fixed it. I had to add an extra column to the right of the first banding area and hide it. The macro that fills in values in the first blue column was causing the banding to expand to the right, and I have no idea why. I will attempt to create another test case.

The sheet that I shared actually shows this behaviour perfectly.

If you click on cell B2 and open up the "Alternating colours" dialog, it shows the area as overlapping column E. This is clearly wrong, and is a symptom of the problem. I should not be surprised that the banding reappears when I enter a value in cell E3.

However, if you click on cell B9 and open up "Alternating colours", it shows that the banding area does NOT overlap column E. Nonetheless, enter a value in cell E9 and the banding expands. This is the bug: why are the alternating colours expanding to cover column E when I enter a value in it?

Answer (score 1):

I have added a sheet ("Erik Help") that does not rely on your script at all. I set up two custom CF rules as follows:

ORANGE (applied to B1:D13,H1:K13)

`=IF(ISEVEN(VLOOKUP(ROW(B1),FILTER(ROW($A:$A),NOT(ISNUMBER($K:$K))),1,TRUE)),ISODD(ROW(B1)),ISEVEN(ROW(B1)))`

BLUE (applied to E1:G)

`=ISNUMBER($K1)`

That's it. And there doesn't seem to be any problem. So my recommendation would be to delete your script and just use the custom CF rules above.

**How The Rules Work:**

ORANGE:

`FILTER` creates a list of only the rows where there is no value in Column K (i.e., rows for main headers). Then `VLOOKUP` looks up each row number within that `FILTER`ed list, finding the closest one backward to any current row. If that found row `ISEVEN`, then the current row will be colored if it `ISODD` and vice versa.

BLUE:

This equates to saying, "If there is any number value in Column K, color this row."

Comment: Interesting. I fixed it by editing the ranges of the "Alternating colours" though, so that they end at column D instead of overlapping to columns E or F. Also, in the real sheet, some of the rows don't have numbers in column K. There isn't a single column guaranteed to have a number in it.

Comment: Keep in mind that we can only act on what you show us. So what is the "rule" (or set of "rules") your script is following as to which rows should be banded? For instance, is it always a group of five rows after a sub-header? Do the sub-headers have some common string portion that other rows don't. If not these, what? If a script can apply a "rule," so can a custom CF rule, generally speaking.

Comment: There is no simple "rule" that I could easily express, it's just "the areas that are banded". I wanted to stop the banding from appearing in the blue area. The script applies the banding to the named ranges. So I guess that's the rule, "if it's one of this set of named ranges". Anyway the problem is solved no, thanks!